# Could someone help explain what this Bash script is doing?

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to linux and although I am familiar with the concept of a lockfile in scripts, I came across that code in another script and thought it was pretty cool, albeit I have no idea how it works. Would anyone be kind enough to go through exactly what the cleanup file and finalize function is doing?

As opposed to a if else statement for a lockfile

```
cleanup_file="$(mktemp -q)"
finalize()
{ 
  set +e
  if test -f "$cleanup_file"
  then
    while read f
    do
      unlink "$f"
    done < "$cleanup_file"
    unlink "$cleanup_file"
  fi
}

trap 'finalize' HUP INT QUIT TERM EXIT
```

Comment: For your question to make sense, there must be use of the `temp` file created with `cleanup_file="$(mktemp -q)"` within your script. The `trap` calls `finalize` (essentially whenever the script exits or is otherwise killed). Presumably there symlinks written to the temporary file which is what the `finalize` function gets rid of.

Answer (score 2):

The `finalize` function isn't dealing with any locks.  It just removes all files whose names are in the cleanup file.  It also removes the cleanup file.

It appears that the larger script appends names of temp files to the cleanup file and the `trap` signal handler takes care of cleaning them up upon termination of the script.

Comment: It looks like the temp file must contain a list of symlinks created during script execution.

Comment: Given that the script is calling `unlink` on the cleanup file as well, my guess is that `unlink` is being used synonymously with `rm`.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now! Although could you elaborate on unlink being used synonymously with rm?

Comment: `unlink` is a simpler version of `rm` and it works on files only, and not directories.  It simply calls the `unlink` system call for the files passed.  `rm` is a more powerful utility which handles files, directories, recursive removal etc.  `rm file` and `unlink file` are equivalent.